# Algo gets the timeout for the Integer.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I have an algorithm that provides the factors of an integer from the 1 to N. The code is provided below,

```
public static int solution(int N) {

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 1; (i * i) <= N; i++) {

            if (i * i == N) {
                count++;

                return count;
            }

            if (N % i == 0) {
                count += 2;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
```

This works fine, but, obviously breaks for the very large value of the integer, for example, `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. How do I improve the code for the VERY large value?

Comment: You can use BigInteger instead of int

Comment: Is this code finding divisors of `N` or its factors? Either way `count` is not right

Comment: You can use `long`s, and it's not enough, then yes: `BigInteger`.

Comment: @ernest_k Where does the count go wrong? You mean negative values?

Comment: I think you have re-think the solution. You can count the numbers from 1 - N and multiple by 2. Then subtract count of square number that you see from 1 - N.

Comment: @JudeNiroshan The solution is correct if you can cast a `long` to hold the larger value.

Comment: @Arefe yes, Indeed. But I was thinking is this is the optimal solution for larger inputs.

Comment: @JudeNiroshan Any optimal solution would include more math, probably prime factorization of `N`, from which you can compute the divisor count directly.

Comment: @maaartinus agreed! It doesn't appear to be an optimized solution. A better approach will be to use the sieve of Eratosthenes to find the primes and use them to find the divisors fasters. But, with the provided code (answered), I received 100% accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your for loop condition as below and it should work.

```
 for (int i = 1; (i * i) > 0 && (i * i) <= N; i++) {
```

This change is needed because of the overflow that occurs at `46341` and any square from this number results in a negative value(most likely, as overflow is an undefined behaviour)  and results in satisfying the condition of `(i * i) <= N` and the loop continues further. So, just add an additional check that the square should be > 0 to handle such case.

Comment: This is very helpful as I was not aware of the negative values. We can also cast the container as the `long` and I get `100%` of the correctness.

Answer (score 1):

If `N == Integer.MAX_VALUE`, `(i * i) <= N` will always be `true`, since the result of `int` multiplication cannot be higher than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Therefore the loop never terminates.

You could change `i` to `long`, which will support larger values of `N`.

Comment: Not correct. Please, have a look inside the code,
 
        `if (i * i == N) {
                count++;

                return count;
            }`

Comment: @Arefe that won't help you, since the square root of Integer.MAX_VALUE is not an integer (it's 46340.95...), so the `if (i * i == N)` condition will never be true.

Comment: Also, I believe the issue is if you increase the value from the square root of the `int`,  the square becomes negative and thus makes it an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your algorithm to divide by `i` instead of multiplying by `i` so that the highest number will always be the input.  This will allow `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to function without changing the datatype:

```
public static int solution(int N) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; (N / i) >= i; i++) {
        if (N / i == i) {
            count++;
            return count;
        }
        if (N % i == 0) {
            count += 2;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Note the `for` condition and first `if` conditions are now `(N / i) >= i` and `N / i == i` which will have the same functionality as before.

Answer (score 0):

The answer @vivek_23 provided is correct, but, also we can cast the container in the condition to a `long` as `(long) i * i <= N` and this will solve the problem,

```
public static int solution(int N) {

        int result = 0;


        // int i = 46341;
        for (int i = 1; (long) i * i <= N; i++) {

            /*
             * we only have one factor
             * */
            if (i * i == N) {
                return ++result;
            }

            /*
             * we get 2 factors/ divisors ie i and (N/i)
             * */
            else if (N % i == 0) {
                result += 2;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```